# How to upgrade to specific macos version

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have macOS 11.6 and would like to upgrade to 12.6, but newer macos 13.0 was released and I'm unsure how to get to upgrade to 12 Monterey anymore. When I open Settings -> Software Update, it offers only latest upgrade and in a "other available" minor update to 11.7.

The reason is that 13.0 is not yet supported in my company so I expect a lot of problems with apps and services internally, while 12 is now well tested.

How to upgrade to a specific MacOS version?

Answer (score 3):

If you manage to find the OS in the app store, you can download and install it. Direct search in app store was not useful for me, but I found 12.x Monterey via google, and it opened a link in app store.

Here is the link for MacOS 12 https://apps.apple.com/au/app/macos-monterey/id1576738294

Comment: Thank you, I needed this for my own situation. Glad I am able to download this so it's compatible with my device! Thanks for the direct link, super helpful.

Comment: @codeadventurer I have macbook pro 2015 and catalina installed. Is it OK to install on it? I have several cli based tools like Python, docker etc installed and chrome, tablePlus